# How to restrict profiling to specific block of code

Tags: profiling

When the following code is executing, how would one restrict the collection of profiling data (say, from vtune) to the second routine?:

while(1){
set_up_code_not_to_be_profiled();
actual_work_needing_to_be_profiled();
}